# Is there a way to check if Filebeat received any UDP packets?

Tags: elasticsearch, udp, logstash, kibana, filebeat

**In my filebeat.yml file I have this:**

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: udp
  host: "localhost:15656"
  enabled: true

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
  username: "elastic"
  password: "changeme"
```

Following the guide here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-installation-configuration.html#start

I sent the command: **filebeat setup -e** followed by **sudo service filebeat start**
checking the status shows that it is listening for UDP connection:

```
Mar 22 11:07:20 ip-172-41-12-144 filebeat[425]: 2021-03-22T11:07:20.706Z        INFO        udp/input.go:99        Starting UDP input
Mar 22 11:07:20 ip-172-41-12-144 filebeat[425]: 2021-03-22T11:07:20.706Z        INFO        [UDP]        dgram/server.go:96        **Started listening for UDP connection**
Mar 22 11:07:20 ip-172-41-12-144 filebeat[425]: 2021-03-22T11:07:20.707Z        INFO        cfgfile/reload.go:164        Config reloader started
Mar 22 11:07:20 ip-172-41-12-144 filebeat[425]: 2021-03-22T11:07:20.707Z        INFO        cfgfile/reload.go:224        Loading of config files completed.
```

But I have no way of knowing if I recieved any UDP packets. Would be great if something was outputted on the screen whenever a packet was received. I don't see anything in elasticsearch or kibana and I know for certain I am sending the packets correctly as logstash could receive them. I stopped using logstash because it was too slow on my server so I tried using filebeat instead but I can't make it receive UDP packets...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to replace the `elasticsearch` output by the [`console` one](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/console-output.html), so that each event you receive will be shown in your terminal:

```
#output.elasticsearch:
#  hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
#  username: "elastic"
#  password: "changeme"

output.console:
  pretty: true
```

Comment: I had to run "systemctl stop filebeat". then run in manually (usr/share/filebeat/bin# ./filebeat -e -c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml) after the change you suggested but all I get is this outputted in the terminal:   INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:144  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s          followed by some info. Any ideas?

Comment: That means nothing is coming through the port. Try generating some fake data yourself [using netcat](https://help.ubidots.com/en/articles/937233-sending-tcp-udp-packets-using-netcat): `nc -u localhost 15656`

Comment: thanks, I was able to work out the setting was wrong. Change output.elasticsearch host to "0.0.0.0" instead of "localhost". Looks like elasticsearch.yml had 0.0.0.0 as well so I just got the address wrong

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out